# Cross-Origin Request Blocked when accessing O365 Rest API

Tags: cors, office365

I'm attempting to creating a partial mail client in an asp.net mvc application.  I'm not using the .net API's as I'm required to get the messages on the client side via javascript.

Unfortunately, I get the following error when attempting to get messages via an ajax request.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages. This can be fixed
>   by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

this is my ajax request

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Authorization": authToken },
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            // response
        },
        error: function (request, errorType, error) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?  I don't know much about CORS.

Comment: It turns out that you have to use dataType: jsonp on the ajax request to resolve the CORS error.  Unfortunately, now I get the parsererror: "jQuery110209297322560211628_1424989995643 was not called".  I'm guessing the O365 API doesn't use the data type jsonp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Office 365 APIs explicitly don't support [cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), or CORS. That's basically when a script that executes in the browser (like your AJAX request) in your web page tries to access something outside of the domain of your web page. We have it on our roadmap to support this, but I don't have a specific timeframe to share at this time.

Comment: CORS is now supported, see: http://blogs.office.com/2015/03/06/increasing-opportunities-javascript-developers-office-365-platform/

Comment: Only for Files API right now. The Outlook APIs (Mail, Calendar, Contacts) are coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Since August 2015, developers now have the option to use CORS to send requests to the Office 365 APIs to access, modify, and create data reliably.

Here is the official Microsoft documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-CORS-to-access-files-in-Office-365

And a post of mine illustrating this case with a step by step tutorial:

http://mosshowto.blogspot.fr/2015/11/embed-office-group-sharepoint-online.html